# css - Why the widths of input and button are not the same even though they are using the same classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css and React to create a Button and an Input component.

Button.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Button() {
  return (
    <button className="border border-black bg-slate-100 font-mono text-2xl text-cyan text-center px-7 py-1 rounded hover:bg-teal-200 hover:text-cyan-300">
      77%
    </button>
  );
}
```

Input.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Input() {
  return (
    <input
      className="border border-black bg-slate-100 font-mono text-2xl text-cyan text-center px-7 py-1 rounded hover:bg-teal-200 hover:text-cyan-300"
      value={"77%"}
    />
  );
}
```

However, the width for these components are not the same. I've tried to adjust the `box-sizing` property but it doesn't work.

[image]

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-qf47rm?file=/src/App.js

How can I make sure both of them adjusting their width based on the content?(In this case, both of their value is `77%`, so their width should be the same). 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *"their width should be adjusted accordingly"*? Could you explain what you expect, in as much technical detail as you can muster, so nobody could misinterpret it, even if they wanted to?

Comment: @tao what I mean is that the width for input and button should be the same given that they have the same content

Comment: The default `width` of `<input>` element is determined by its [`size` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/size), which is `20` by default. That's why your `<input>` appears wider than `<button>`

Comment: Thanks, Hao. You are correct, here's [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-size-attribute).